# SilverStripe - Filter DataList results to remove duplicates and group by value

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying something different with DataLists in SilverStripe. The goal is to return a list of stores sorted by state in this format.

There is an admin model that has been created called `StoreLocation.php` which contains the store data:

```
class StoreLocation extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Address'   => 'Varchar(250)',
        'City'      => 'varchar(100)',
        'State'     => 'varchar(2)',
        'Zip'       => 'varchar(10)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Store' => 'Store'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'getStoreSummaryLabel' => 'Store Info'
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Address',
        'City',
        'State',
        'Zip'
    );

    public function getStoreSummaryLabel() {
        $storeName = $this->Store()->Name;
        return sprintf("%s (%s)", $storeName, $this->addressPretty());
    }

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $siteConfig = SiteConfig::current_site_config();

        $statesDropdown = DropdownField::create("State", "State", $siteConfig->stateList())
            ->setEmptyString('Select State');

        if ($siteConfig->GoogleAPIKey == "") {
            $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HeaderField("error","Error: No Google API Key Defined!",2));
        }

        $fields->removeFieldsFromTab('Root.Main', [
            'State',
        ]);

        return $fields;
    }

    public function addressPretty() {
        return sprintf("%s %s, %s %s", $this->data()->Address, $this->data()->City, $this->data()->State, $this->data()->Zip);
    }
}
```

The `Store` `DataObject` which is referenced by `StoreLocation`:

```
class Store extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(100)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Logo' => 'Image'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Locations' => 'StoreLocation'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Name'
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name',
        'Logo'
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        return $fields;
    }

    static $default_sort = "Name ASC";
}
```

The problem is I need to return a list of stores by state but remove any duplicate store names since I am not displaying the store addresses. I only need to display the names (I don't know why. This is just how it has to be). So, for example, there could be 5 results for Store ABC in Alabama because there are 5 locations for it, but I just want to return Store ABC once for Alabama.

Simply returning a list of `StoreLocation` data in this format returns the correct results but with tons of duplicates and the state name is repeated above each store:

UPDATE: I found a possible solution after discovering this link which contains a custom nested grouped lists class file: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/24195

With the use of that class, I was able to make a GroupedList in which I can sort by 2 different aspects of a data object:

```
public function GroupedEntries() {
    return NestedGroupedList::create(
        StoreLocation::get()->sort('State ASC, StoreID ASC')
    );
}
```

Then, in the template, I set up this:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
    <div class="retailer-listing" style="text-align: left;">
        <% loop $GroupedEntries.GroupedBy('State,StoreID') %>
            <strong>$State</strong><br />
                <% loop $Children %>
                        <% loop $Children.First %>
                            $Store.Name<br />
                        <% end_loop %>
                <% end_loop %>
        <% end_loop %>
     </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be returning the correct organization of results, sorting the first instance of each store name alphabetically by state. It took some guess and check testing until I got the loops just right.

Comment: Please share the contents of the  `getAllRetailersByState` function

Comment: Currently, it's what I have at the bottom of my post: $counter =GroupedList::created(StoreLocation::get())->GroupedBy('State')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after discovering this link which contains a custom nested grouped lists class file: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/24195

With the use of that class, I was able to make a GroupedList in which I can sort by 2 different aspects of a data object:

```
public function GroupedEntries() {
    return NestedGroupedList::create(
        StoreLocation::get()->sort('State ASC, StoreID ASC')
    );
}
```

Then, in the template, I set up this:

```
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
        <div class="retailer-listing" style="text-align: left;">
            <% loop $GroupedEntries.GroupedBy('State,StoreID') %>
                <strong>$State</strong><br />
                    <% loop $Children %>
                            <% loop $Children.First %>
                                $Store.Name<br />
                            <% end_loop %>
                    <% end_loop %>
            <% end_loop %>
         </div>
    </div>
```

This seems to be returning the correct organization of results, sorting the first instance of each store name alphabetically by state. It took some guess and check testing until I got the loops just right.

Answer (score 1):

First we create a function to return a `GroupedList` of `StoreLocation` items in our page controller:

```
public function getGroupedStoreLocations() {
    return GroupedList::create(StoreLocation::get()->sort('State'));
}
```

In our page template we then call `GroupedBy(State)` on our `GroupedStoreLocations` function to group the list by. This returns an `ArrayList` of group items, which contain the index (the stage name) and a list of children that belong to this group. Inside our `GroupedStoreLocations` loop we can loop over `$Children` to go through each item in that `GroupedList`:

```
<% loop $GroupedStoreLocations.GroupedBy(State) %>
    <h4>$State</h4>
    <ul>
    <% loop $Children %>
        <li>$Store.Name</li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

View more information on the [`GroupedList` Documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/how_tos/grouping_dataobject_sets/) page.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but the one problem is that the $Children loop returns the name of every store associated with a state--and that means duplicates occur because there can be multiple locations of a store in one state (i.e. There are probably a ton of Walgreens in Ohio and a bunch of Walmarts).

Comment: I'll look into it and see if there is anything we can do.

Comment: I think I may have something. I'll post it here hopefully tomorrow. It's not the greatest thing ever but it seems to work.

Comment: Ok, I added my possible solution to my initial entry

Comment: That's great @DejsaCocan. Post your solution as an answer rather than an edit of your question.